# Displaying a message when something is inserted into a table

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sql-server-2005

In my application I want a message to be displayed when something new is inserted into my table, what's the best way of doing this? the only thing I can think of right now is having a timer repeat a query every few minutes to check if there are any new records.

Comment: [BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Depends on what `my table` is.  The `DataTable` has events such as `RowChanging` and `RowChanged` your app could respond to.

Comment: I would look into **https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345108(v=SQL.90).aspx** which uses service broker. It's relatively easy to set-up and get going as well.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server introduced [Query Notifications](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175110(v=sql.90).aspx) in SQL 2005. Since you are only interested in insertions, you could use a trigger on the table. In that trigger, you'd need to update a secondary table. Then, in your application, your query that needs to be monitored just looks at that secondary table for any changed results.